# Miniconda pointing to wrong install

Tags: python, anaconda, miniconda

I am trying to install a new package using `conda install`. I have miniconda in `/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/miniconda3/` but I also had previously installed miniconda3 in `/home/user/Programmes/`

If I run 
`/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/miniconda3/bin/conda install scipy` the install occurs but installs to miniconda in `/home/user/Programmes`. If I run `/home/user/dir1/dir2/dir3/miniconda3/conda info` I can see that it is pointing to the other miniconda. How can I set this so that the root environment is correct?

```
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.3.25
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.25
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.5.2.final.0
       requests version : 2.13.0
       root environment : /home/user/Programmes/miniconda3  (writable)
    default environment : /home/user/Programmes/miniconda3
       envs directories : /home/user/Programmes/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/user/.conda/envs
          package cache : /home/user/Programmes/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/user/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.25 requests/2.13.0 CPython/3.5.2 Linux/4.4.0-96-generic debian/stretch/sid glibc/2.23    
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
```

Comment: The execution of Python programs will depend on the environment variables `PATH` (location of executables, such as `conda`) and `PYTHONPATH` (from where to load the Python modules). To diagnose your installation a bit more, please state how you installed the newer miniconda (what commands did you type?), what customization has been done by conda in the file `$HOME/.bashrc`?

Comment: The newer miniconda was transferred directly from another machine (if I remember correctly - I've been using it for about a year and haven't needed to update any packages). This was due to it being a fairly complicated install (particularly getting qt5 working) so I just copied an existing version from another machine which I had setup and worked. I don't have anything in .bashrc or .bash_aliases pointing to conda etc. If I type python3 in the terminal I get the system python. If I want the conda python, then I point directly to that directory. Putting the new version in .bashrc doesn't help.

Comment: Can you reproduce the error after restarting the shell?

Comment: Ok, this is not supported, see the [doc of anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory). Miniconda works the same way. If you are willing to try and understand that you risk breaking the system, check this [GH issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/270). The recommended method is to reinstall.